# 10 ranking places of difference between Safari@MacOS and Chrome@Win10

Tags: google, google-search, ranking, google-ranking

My client's site is differently ranked on MacOS and Windows. Safari@MacOS displays his site on place 7, Chrome@Win10 display him on the place 17. Both surely incognito windows. This ranking difference is vera stable, firstly experienced around a year ago and exists since then.

Ranking ins GSC is like at Chrome@Win10 - place 17 for the desktop.

Is there any explanation and reason for such behavior?

Comment: I assume you mean ranking in Google?

Comment: Is it affected by browser or just by OS?  (firefox, chrome, safari on the two platforms)

Comment: yes, its about Google rankings. They affected by OS+browser. MacOS+Chrome delivers rankings more or less similar to GSC.